# Sorting on an array of strings in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using the following to sort documents in Elasticsearch that have a 'usernamesAssigned' property. usernamesAssigned is an array of strings:

```
"sort": [
    {
        "_script": {
            "script": "doc["usernamesAssigned"].values.sort().join()",
            "type": "string",
            "lang": "js",
            "order": "asc"
        }
    }
]
```

I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to do this without using script based sorting?

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I recently wandered across it while trying to solve the same problem...

According to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html):

> Elasticsearch supports sorting by array or multi-valued fields. The
>   mode option controls what array value is picked for sorting the
>   document it belongs to.

So, you should be able to sort like this:

`"sort" : [ {"usernamesAssigned" : {"order" : "asc", "mode" : "min"}} ]`

This has been available since version 0.90.0.Beta1.

Comment: not working for me `{ "query": { "bool": { "must": [{ "range": { "date": { "gte": "2006-10-19T00:00:00.000Z", "lte": "2019-11-01T00:00:00.000Z" } } }] } }, "sort": [{ "from": { "order": "asc", "mode" : "min" } }] }`